# reading comma separated numbers from excel row - python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

How to read excel row and check if the numbers of the first row are the same as the numbers of second row and third ( fourth, fifth, sixth and seventh row ) ? I would like to add user defined number of iterations that should be meet, before creating result.

### I have just one column and 7 rows with 6 comma separated numbers.

This is example based on 2 iterations:

```
column 1
1.) 1,2,3,4,5,6
2.) 1,3,5,7,9,10    ---> 1,3,5
3.) 3,5,7,9,10,11   ---> 3,5
```

---

grouped numbers result ( from each row except first one ): 3,5

Ideas ?
E.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have this file:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(io='path_to_file.xlsx', header=None)

print(df)
# Output:
             0
0    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1   1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10
2  3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11
```

You could try this:

```py
# Setup
previous_row = df.iloc[0]
user_number_of_iterations = 4  # for instance
items = []

# Iterate over dataframe rows and find common values
# between  row[n] and row[n-1]
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if i == 0:
        continue
    if i > user_number_of_iterations:
        break
    a = set(sorted(row.values[0].split(", ")))
    b = set(sorted(previous_row.values[0].split(", ")))
    items.append(a & b)
    previous_row = row
    # Get symmetric difference between two sets
    print(f"Missed numbers at iteration {i}: {a ^ b}")

# Find common values between previous results
result = items[0]
for item in items[1:]:
    result = set(result) & set(item)

print(sorted(result))  # Output: ['3', '5']

# Missed numbers at iteration 1: {'7', '4', '2', '10', '6', '9'}
# Missed numbers at iteration 2: {'11', '1'}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and given answer. I have this file and i can read it out successfully. I forget to mention that my numbers are formatted with one extra blank space, like 1, 2 instead of 1,2. I try to add this additional space into you existing formatting but it looks like it didnt work because i get [] as output. // BTW. How can i print out all "missed" numbers ?

Comment: Simply replace `.split(",")` with `.split(", ")` twice and add a print statement for "missed" numbers, see my updated answer.

Comment: i removed the blank space and this is the result : [u'10', u'3', u'5', u'7', u'9']. @nk03 am using xls file but thank you for suggestion.

Comment: You seem to deal with unicode strings. Try adding `for col in df.columns: df[col] = df[col].astype(str)` at the beginning and see if it changes something.

Comment: You last suggestion has helped regarding formatting, thank you. I found one problem and we need to change logic of the program. First row is not recognized at 0 position. Second row has 0 position so program makes compare with second row as starting row. How to change that ? // 2.) before we make group, we need to compare the numbers that are repeated in each row, then we will have "correct" printout. Please look at attached photo. https://ibb.co/2jzXz5N  Just to describe this better, i would like to group results of  "B" column... Anyways, thank you for your effort..

Comment: Your problems come from the fact that you're not correctly importing your xls file, add a `header` parameter as in my updated answer and have a look to the documentation to know more: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. If you wish, you can also add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle. In any case, good luck!

Comment: Can you help me out to group the data as shown on xls picture ? This is the main goal... I clicked the triangle but i can not find check mark, or i need glasses :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this -

Assuming you’ve a comma seperated csv file.

```
from functools import reduce
result = reduce(lambda x,y: x.intersection(y), df.apply(set, axis=1).values) # {3,5}
```